# access to json Api objects using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api

I want to get access to json api objects using jquery:

```
"schedule":{"time":"22:00","days":["Wednesday","Thursday"]}
```

and i'm using this jquery code to get time data:

```
jQuery.getJSON("http://api.tvmaze.com/lookup/shows?imdb=" + co + "",    function(data) {
        jQuery.each(data, function(key, val) {
            jQuery('input[name=' + key + ']').val(val);    
             if (key == "schedule") {
                    var tim = "";
                    jQuery.each(data.schedule, function(i, item) {
                        tim += item.time;
                    });
                    jQuery('#schedule_time').val(tim);
                }
            });
```

but nothing will show in output! 
please help!

```
"network":{"id":128,"name":"KBS2","country":{"name":"Korea, Republic of","code":"KR","timezone":"Asia/Seoul"}}
```

Comment: provide full code. where you get `key`?

Comment: I get the key from the top json code "schedule".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (key == "schedule") {
    // val == {"time":"22:00","days":["Wednesday","Thursday"]}
    jQuery('#schedule_time').val(val.time);
}
```

Since you already have access to the result of schedule, you don't need to create another loop.  Just access the time directly.

Comment: @bashirsaboori You can access the timezone in the second object you posted using network.country.timezone

Comment: @bashirsaboori it may be helpful if you post a new question.  It's difficult to determine the issue without more context, which is difficult to establish in comments.